# Multiple rows returned when only one per part is desired

Tags: sql-server

Good Afternoon,

The SQL below returns multiple rows per pr_codenum.  The desired result is one row per.  I tried using a GROUP BY without any change to the results.  The columns P01, P02, etc. are facility locations that will have a true, false or blank if they do not use a particular pr_codenum.  There will ultimately be 20 columns. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.
Thank you
GQ

```
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY wa_name) AS RowID, wa_id
    INTO #LOC 
    FROM "SomeTable"
    WHERE IsUsingTable = 1

    SELECT DISTINCT pr_codenum, pr_descrip, 
        CASE WHEN RowID = 1 THEN HazMatFlag ELSE '' END AS P01,
        CASE WHEN RowID = 2 THEN HazMatFlag ELSE '' END AS P02,
        CASE WHEN RowID = 3 THEN HazMatFlag ELSE '' END AS P03,
        CASE WHEN RowID = 4 THEN HazMatFlag ELSE '' END AS P04,
        CASE WHEN RowID = 5 THEN HazMatFlag ELSE '' END AS P05,
        CASE WHEN RowID = 6 THEN HazMatFlag ELSE '' END AS P06,
        CASE WHEN RowID = 7 THEN HazMatFlag ELSE '' END AS P07,
        CASE WHEN RowID = 8 THEN HazMatFlag ELSE '' END AS P08,
        CASE WHEN RowID = 9 THEN HazMatFlag ELSE '' END AS P09,
        CASE WHEN RowID = 10 THEN HazMatFlag ELSE '' END AS P010,
        CASE WHEN RowID = 11 THEN HazMatFlag ELSE '' END AS P011,
        CASE WHEN RowID = 12 THEN HazMatFlag ELSE '' END AS P012,
        CASE WHEN RowID = 13 THEN HazMatFlag ELSE '' END AS P013,
        CASE WHEN RowID = 14 THEN HazMatFlag ELSE '' END AS P014
    FROM (
        SELECT RowID, pr_codenum, pr_descrip, CASE WHEN p3_hazflag = 1 THEN 
    'True' ELSE 'False' END AS HazMatFlag 
    FROM "SomeTable" 
    INNER JOIN "AnotherTable" ON p3_prid = pr_id
    INNER JOIN "DifferentTable" ON wa_id = p3_waid  
    LEFT JOIN #LOC l ON l.wa_id = p3_waid
    WHERE pr_id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT p3_prid FROM "YetAnotherTable" 
        INNER JOIN "Table" ON pr_id = p3_prid AND pr_active = 1
        WHERE p3_hazflag = 0 AND p3_prid IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT p3_prid FROM "YetAnotherTable" 
            INNER JOIN "Table" ON pr_id = p3_prid AND pr_active = 1 
            WHERE p3_hazflag = 1))
    )g              
    GROUP BY pr_codenum, pr_descrip, RowID, HazMatFlag
    ORDER BY pr_codenum

    DROP TABLE #LOC
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want aggregation:

```
SELECT pr_codenum, pr_descrip, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN RowID = 1 THEN HazMatFlag ELSE '' END) AS P01,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RowID = 2 THEN HazMatFlag ELSE '' END) AS P02,
      . . .
FROM . . .
GROUP BY pr_codenum, pr_descrip
ORDER BY pr_codenum
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your separating every distinct row number into its own column, since every row will have a value in a different column, your distinct returns every row.

I've wrapped your P columns into a max.  If a row contains a hazmatflag, the max should pick that up rather then the '', and your group by should allow this to aggregate to the pr_codenum, pr_descrip.  This of course assumes that your hazmatflag values are greater than an empty string and that your descrip value is the same for a codenum of the same value.

```
SELECT  RowID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY wa_name),
        wa_id
INTO    #LOC
  FROM  "SomeTable"
  WHERE IsUsingTable = 1
;

SELECT      pr_codenum,
            pr_descrip,
            P01 = MAX( CASE WHEN g.RowID = 1 THEN g.HazMatFlag ELSE '' END ),
            P02 = MAX( CASE WHEN g.RowID = 2 THEN g.HazMatFlag ELSE '' END ),
            P03 = MAX( CASE WHEN g.RowID = 3 THEN g.HazMatFlag ELSE '' END ),
            P04 = MAX( CASE WHEN g.RowID = 4 THEN g.HazMatFlag ELSE '' END ),
            P05 = MAX( CASE WHEN g.RowID = 5 THEN g.HazMatFlag ELSE '' END ),
            P06 = MAX( CASE WHEN g.RowID = 6 THEN g.HazMatFlag ELSE '' END ),
            P07 = MAX( CASE WHEN g.RowID = 7 THEN g.HazMatFlag ELSE '' END ),
            P08 = MAX( CASE WHEN g.RowID = 8 THEN g.HazMatFlag ELSE '' END ),
            P09 = MAX( CASE WHEN g.RowID = 9 THEN g.HazMatFlag ELSE '' END ),
            P010 = MAX( CASE WHEN g.RowID = 10 THEN g.HazMatFlag ELSE '' END ),
            P011 = MAX( CASE WHEN g.RowID = 11 THEN g.HazMatFlag ELSE '' END ),
            P012 = MAX( CASE WHEN g.RowID = 12 THEN g.HazMatFlag ELSE '' END ),
            P013 = MAX( CASE WHEN g.RowID = 13 THEN g.HazMatFlag ELSE '' END ),
            P014 = MAX( CASE WHEN g.RowID = 14 THEN g.HazMatFlag ELSE '' END )
  FROM
            ( SELECT        l.RowID,
                            pr_codenum,
                            pr_descrip,
                            HazMatFlag = CASE WHEN p3_hazflag = 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END
                FROM        "SomeTable"
                INNER JOIN  "AnotherTable"
                  ON p3_prid = pr_id
                INNER JOIN  "DifferentTable"
                  ON wa_id = p3_waid
                LEFT JOIN   #LOC AS l
                  ON l.wa_id = p3_waid
                WHERE       pr_id IN ( SELECT       DISTINCT
                                                    p3_prid
                                         FROM       "YetAnotherTable"
                                         INNER JOIN "Table"
                                           ON pr_id = p3_prid
                                              AND   pr_active = 1
                                         WHERE      p3_hazflag = 0
                                                    AND p3_prid IN ( SELECT         DISTINCT
                                                                                    p3_prid
                                                                       FROM         "YetAnotherTable"
                                                                       INNER JOIN   "Table"
                                                                         ON pr_id = p3_prid
                                                                            AND pr_active = 1
                                                                       WHERE        p3_hazflag = 1 ))) AS g
  GROUP BY  pr_codenum,
            pr_descrip
  ORDER BY  pr_codenum
;

DROP TABLE #LOC
;
```